# Python: Is it possible to "multiply" a text string to print out repetitions of that string?

Tags: python, automation, global-variables, variable-assignment

I'm new to python and learning about variables and how they can be manipulated. I've created and use a variable that contains the code for a new line: \n. Then, I call that function in my scripts to create a nice, readable user output. e.g.

```
NL = "\n"
print ("Hello, world.",NL)
```

So I'm challenging myself to learn how to make that NL variable **change** based on user input. For example, maybe I'd like to have TWO new lines when I call the variable, and not one. So I've scripted a (failed) solution that asks for my input and then tries to write THAT NUMBER of repeatable \n's in sequence. For example, if I ask for 3 new lines, I'd like the variable to reflect that as NL = "\n\n\n"

My logic (pseudo code) to create the result:

- ask for the number of new lines I'd like and set to a variable
- confirm the input's correct, else run the function from the start
- convert the input to an integer
- create a global variable to be able to use it outside of the function
- set the global variable as the result of multiplying \n by the integer
- confirm to user that the variable has been set correctly

My function is shown. I'd like a direction and suggestions to improve my solution.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
def NL():
    newLine="\n"
    howMany = input('How many returns should I pleace in each linebreak? ')
    print("You've entered",howMany,"returns.")
    confirm = input('Correct? y/n? ')
    if confirm == "n":
        print("Sorry, let's try that again.",NL())
    else:    
        x=int(howMany) 
        global y
        y = print("\n" * x)
        print("OK, every line break will now contain",x,"new lines.")
NL()
```

Comment: Ok, I think I've solved my own problem. Looks like I needed to change:
        y = print("\n" * x)

Into: 
        y = "\n" * x

Comment: Yes, with your correction it works; but it would be better to _return_ the value from the function instead of assigning it to a global variable. This way you can call your function and assign the value to the variable you need: more flexible, and less error prone (the time you will set `y` and forget that your function modifies it

Comment: @gimix - thanks for the reply. I'm not yet sure how to return the value of a function but will research it. One thing I HAVE learned is this: if I make my script a module, and import that module into a different script, my global variable "y" will not carry into the new script. Hopefully, your solution fixes that.

Comment: just add `return y` or forget about `y` and do `return "\n" * x`